# Why would Ubuntu treat NXDOMAIN as resolving to localhost?

Tags: 18.04, dns, localhost, systemd-resolved

Every time I should be getting an error because a domain does not exist (e.g. `could not resolve host`), I instead get an error about connecting to a loopback address:

```
$ curl -4 -v https://nonexist.invalid
Trying 127.0.0.1...
```

The problem only starts occuring about 2 seconds after establishing a wireless connection. For a short time, all works as expected.

I am using `systemd-resolved` and dns appears to be working:

```
$ readlink /etc/resolv.conf
../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolve.conf
$ dig +short A example.com
192.0.2.1
$ dig +short A nonexist.invalid
$ systemd-resolve -t A nonexist.invalid
nonexist.invalid: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
```

**If name resolution looks okay, why would programs still appear to be resolving names to `127.0.0.1`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's DNS. The **search domain** setting is causing this:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search localhost
```

A router tricked Ubuntu into expanding names with a search domain that receives special treatment from *systemd-resolved* and as such breaks expected behavior:

> The hostnames "localhost" and "localhost.localdomain" (**as well as any hostname ending in ".localhost"** or ".localhost.localdomain") are resolved to the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1.

**Solution A: Reconfigure the router** to send a more appropriate search domain

**Solution B: disable automatic DNS configuration**, e.g. in NetworkManager you can disable it just for either Ipv4 or IPv6 if the issue is limited to one. The corresponding option in the text config format is `ignore-auto-dns`.

```
# /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WLAN
# ..
[ipv6]
ignore-auto-dns=true
# ..
```

**Not a solution: edit /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf** (this configuration cannot supersede IPv6 Router Advertisment DNSSL)